# Is it efficient to read from a LIST of FILES instead of a PATH in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning, azure-databricks

I am using pyspark in azure databricks. And need to **load thousands of files as a list of files**. "***Multi depth partitioning***" is used, which makes difficult to use the base path to read the files.

Indeed, this multi-depth partitions results in nested directories which trigger this error :

> AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for CSV. It must be
> specified manually.;

Hence, we are reading everything as a list of files and I would like to know if the performance is the same when you read files using :

**1.**

```
spark.read.format('csv').load('/mnt/article/2021/08/09')
```

vs

**2.**

```
spark.read.format('csv').load([
        '/mnt/article/2021/08/09/test.csv',
        '/mnt/article/2021/08/09/test2.csv',
        '/mnt/article/2021/08/09/test3.csv'
    ])
```

vs

**3.**

```
spark.read.format('csv').load(['/mnt/article/*/*/*/])
```

For some reasons, we don't want to use the third one : `spark.read.format('csv').load(['/mnt/article/*/*/*/)` but we might reconsider if the second one is really not efficient.

Many thanks in advance for any observations or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try it by yourself, it is a good exercise.

However, I would say `2nd` option is slightly faster because it does not require extra ls.

But I am not even sure of that because Spark checks if the files are leaves or not. It probably depends on the implementation of the connector. cf: [def allFiles(): Seq[FileStatus]](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/PartitioningAwareFileIndex.scala#L105)

Except if you have thousands of files on a file system where `ls` costs (typically a cloud provider where an `ls` is an HTTP request). It should not make a difference and you should choose the clearest option from a business point of view. Which is the `1st` option you offered.